# Touchpad and keybord not working properly

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have ubuntu 16.04 with windows 8 dual boot. Recently out of the blue touchpad and keyboard stopped working properly.
In touchpad mouse movement is fine. So is left and right click. But left click doesnt happen if i simply tap the touchpad. Scrolling also doesnt happen

In keyboard i cannot hold a key to get multiple press. Eg. keep holding a key only types one letter.

I am new to ubuntu please help.

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948).  Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment here using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment.

Comment: Thank you! So this is a update issue with me too. Problem is Touchpadoff becomes 2 itself after sometime. Right now i am using script, `synclient Touchpadoff=0` every 5 sec and touchpad works fine. I can tolerate problem with keyboard. Will upgrade to new version later and inform if problem exists! @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer with short term Touchpad fix in addition to the short term Keyboard fix. Both fixes could work without having to update the Kernel (which I haven't gotten feedback on yet).